# Textchanged event is not firing when using jscript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my asp.net application, i am using a lookup to enter data to a textbox.For making lookup i have used jscript.I have a button for this lookup from which i am entering data to this textbox.so, i am not entering values directly to the textbox.After entering values to textbox, the textchanged event is not working.What could be the reason?

Comment: Please provide your code snippet for us to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Could it simply be that the textbox is not receiving, and more importantly not losing focus? The textchanged event will only fire when the textbox loses focus.